# WPF window on closing

Tags: wpf

I want send some data on server, before window close. I use event closing, but it doesn t wokr. Where is a problem?

```
    private void Window_Closing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            _obj.CloseConnection();

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Try overriding OnClosing in the window code behind. There you have a chance to stop the window from closing if you have something else to do by setting `e.Cancel = true`.

```
    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       bool isClosed = _obj.CloseConnection();

       if(!isClosed)
          e.Cancel = true;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if there's a problem on _obj.CloseConnection()? Try to debug your code and check if the event handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way without overriding the OnClosing.

The constructor of the main window is

```
       public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        Closing += MainWindow_Closing;
    }
```

Then create an event handler

```
        private void MainWindow_Closing(object? sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
       // do something
     }
```

Note: This may not meet MVVM.

D