# WPF Window IsClosing bool

Tags: wpf, window

I want to have the same command when I click the "Cancel" button or when I close the window (ALT+F4 or click the x).
The problem is the command will eventually close the window that is in the "closing" mode which is denied - I can't close a window that is closing.
How can I distinguish the mode "IsClosing" in the window? It doesnt have this bool property ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for. If you provide some code to show what you're trying to do now, I could probably help you better.

In the meantime, this question seems to be asking something similar to yours. Why don't you check this out and see if it helps?

[WPF window on closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411828/wpf-window-on-closing)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine I would have 2 different behaviours in a Window.

- Drop data - when I cancel or ALT+F3.
- Persist data - when I click the Ok button.

The only way I have to catch the ALT+F4 action is on closing event. My solution was to have a flag that is true only when I enter the window with te OK command. I test that flag, persist data if true or drop data otherwise.