# Best way to intercept closing of window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for the best way to intercept the closing of a window in my software. For example I want to intercept the closure of a form called "settings", and not the MainWindow. vb.net of the procedure was very simple, I had only to call its closing event, but with WPF I can not understand why this event is not captured, and as a result, the code inside is not executed.

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you're trying to do / capture? I haven't done too much with WPF but you should be able to do something along the lines of `using (MyForm mf = new MyForm()) { if (mf.ShowDialog() == DialogResults.OK) // do stuff }`. That's more WinForms stuff but again without seeing what you're trying...

Comment: Are you [overriding OnClosing](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2411871/1336590)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the form you want to intercept the closing for:

```
    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if(dontClose)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
        base.OnClosing(e);
    }
```

Replace dontClose with your conditions for not closing.

Comment: overriding OnClosing does not include an object sender

Comment: I'd suggest to call the base class method before checking the condition, just in case it sets `e.Cancel = false;`.

Comment: @Clemens -- While this is a good point, there is controversy as to which way this should go.  Often times programmers want the derived class to reset Cancel to false in certain circumstances.  As far as I know, the default OnClosing event doesn't change Cancel, so the only way for it to change is if you've programmed the derived class to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In the cs file behind your XAML, add this:

```
    // Constructor
    public SettingsWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Closing += SettingsWindow_Closing; // Subscribe to window closing event.
    }

    // Window closing event handler.
    private void SettingsWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add method you want to run on close here.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can acces it from the view model as well if you have one. Like this

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Closing += (s, e) =>{ your code comes here};
```